# Find $b$ such that $5^b=73$ in $U(1024)$.

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups

I have a doubt on the following. Kindly show where did the argument go wrong.

In the multiplicative group $U(1024)$ (the group of units of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{2^{10}}$), the order of $5, 73$ are $256, 128$ respectively. Assuming that $73=5^b$ for some positive integer $b$ we have: $128=|73|=|5^b|$. As $|5|=256$, it follows $b=2$.

But this is not true because $73\neq 5^2$. I checked in Maple17, it showed $73=5^{2.7.13}$. I am really getting no clue which part did I make wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only showed that the order of $5^2$ equals the order of $73$, which is correct. You cannot conclude from $o(a)=o(b)$ that $a=b$ in a group $G$.

For example, take the group $C_2\times C_2=\{e,a,b,c\}$ with $o(a)=o(b)=o(c)=2$. Of course, this does not imply that $a=b=c$ in $C_2\times C_2$.

Comment: ok.  now i realize my mistake. thanks a lot.